# Do we need to spend Gas to move ERC20 token inside a bip32/HD wallet

Tags: gas, erc-20, hd-wallets

I just wondering to know in order to move erc20 token inside a bip32/HD wallet from child to parent to we need to spend any gas? (example: imagine I made a HD wallet which supporting ERC20 tokens and my HD wallet structure has a parent and 10  child, if one of child receive few ERC20 token from an ICO  under his/her public key  and want to move/transfer it to parent public key does he needs to spend any Gas in ETH or same token ?

Answer (score 1):

One private key corresponds always to one public key and one address. HD wallets are just a way or organizing your private keys in an easier-to-manage way.

In the end a HD wallet is just a collection of different private keys and therefore a collection of different public addresses. In order to transfer tokens (or Ethers) between different addresses you need Ethers to pay for the gas costs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer ERC20 token from child to parent of hd wallet, then gas used in ETH from you child wallet.